# ssh user@pc 'source ~/.bashrc;printenv' doesn't source bashrc?

Tags: bash, openssh

passing commands through ssh , but path not found due to the sourcing issue. no change after source. Some machines it works fine.

`ssh user@pc 'source ~/.bashrc;printenv'`

```
SSH_CONNECTION=192.168.5.249 59060 192.168.5.248 22
LANG=en_IN
XDG_SESSION_ID=57
USER=hadoop
PWD=/home/hadoop
HOME=/home/hadoop
SSH_CLIENT=192.168.5.249 59060 22
MAIL=/var/mail/hadoop
SHELL=/bin/bash
SHLVL=1
LANGUAGE=en_IN:en
LOGNAME=hadoop
DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:path=/run/user/1001/bus
XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/1001

PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games
_=/usr/bin/printenv
```

bashrc in user home not loaded even though it is passed.

Comment: `printenv` is no builtin command. Try `set` or export variable.

Comment: Try running: `ssh user@pc /bin/bash -c 'source ~/.bashrc;printenv'`

Comment: Could you [edit] your question to explain more clearly what the actual problem is? Maybe include your .bashrc in the question if you think parts of it aren't executing.

Comment: just moving the path to bash profile then source. ssh user source ~/.bash_profile;printenv. This worked for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just moving the path to bash profile then source.

```
ssh user@pc 'source ~/.bash_profile;printenv'
```

This worked for me.